# Как преобразовать число чтобы оно имело количество значащих цифр после десятичной точки не более чем у другого числа?

Tags: python, float, числа, int

Имеется 2 числа `A` и `B`, где число `В` как шаблон:

```
A = 123.12345678
B = 0.00100000
```

Как сделать на Python, чтобы число `А` имело количество  значащих цифр после десятичной точки, не более чем у числа `В`?

T.е. должно получится так:

```
А = 123.12300000
```

или так:

```
А = 123.123
```

Comment: У числа не бывает "шага". Определите требования более чётко.

Comment: Из-за специфики работы с числами с плавающей точкой ваш вопрос по сути не имеет практического смысла, только если вы не будете в работать со строковым представлением чисел.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @Akina. Требования определены очень размыто. Внесите ясность, чтобы членам сообщества было проще дать ответ.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста мою правку. Она не исказила смысл вашего вопроса? А то не совсем понятно, что такое шаблон и что такое шаг.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
In [52]: round(A, len(str(B).split('.')[1]))
Out[52]: 123.123
```

Но это будет работать не всегда из-за природы чисел с плавающей точкой:

```
In [56]: C = 0.1 + 0.2

In [57]: str(C)
Out[57]: '0.30000000000000004'
```

Comment: *но это будет работать не всегда* особенно если продемонстрированный фортель выкинет число В...

Comment: @Akina, ну, я вроде об этом и написал... ;)

Comment: Я вообще о том, что автору походу после округления надо ещё на хвост нулей натолкать (т.е., вероятно, нужен второй round, но с исходной точностью) - тут может вылезти бяка с неточным представлением округлённого первого числа. Ведь не факт, что всё это нужно чисто чтобы на экран - мож, оно потом в вычислениях используется как-то.

Comment: @Akina, я, честно говоря, подумал, что нули в конце значения не имеют...